# Why RecyclerView is not working setBackground function?

Tags: scroll, android-recyclerview

I tried many Times for setting backgroundColor on RecyclerView. but i try to scroll then background was removed.So I can fix backgroundColor in RecyclerView. Help me please.

Or I Want to change ForegroundColor.

My Issue Video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C29qhPb44FE

I don't know the reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first understand how RecyclerView works.

As you scroll through the cells, the views that gets out of the screen will be RECYCLED, and they will subsequently be reused to display the incoming views. Hence the name RecyclerView. This way, views will always be recycled and reused, thus saving memory.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //mList and mSelectedObjects are array lists
    View yourView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.your_view);
    Object object = mList.get(position);
    yourView.setTag(object);
    yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Object object = (Object) v.getTag();
            if (mSelectedObjects.contains(object)) {
                mSelectedObjects.remove(object);
                v.setBackground(null);
            } else {
                mSelectedObjects.add(object);
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jagoan Neon. exactly i dont know how to adapt my code. anyway Im really Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you set programmatically the background color. You have to set every time the normal color and the selected color.

RecyclerViews are reusing their views. When an item leaves the screen it will be reused to increase the performance of the recycler view.

In this case when one set programmatically a background color and the item leaves the screen. It will be reused in the new item and the background color is still the same as when the item has left the screen.